# Any ORM without hardcoding table structure in Java?

Tags: java, activerecord, orm, jooq, spring-orm

I have tables already created in database.

I.e. database is first.

Database structure can be changed.

I don't want to rewrite ORM fields myself for this structure. I don't want to regenerate any mappings with any tools like Hibernate or JPA tools.

I.e. any database reflection should be made at runtime.

Can I still have some benefits from any ORM library like Spring Data JPA, Hibernate, jOOQ etc in this situation?

I would still prefer some getters like

```
public Object get(String fieldName);
```

and setters like

```
public void set(String fieldName, Object fieldValue);
```

This is implemented in [Apache's DynaBean](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBean.html), for example.

Simultaneously I wish to have `Active Record` i.e. object instance represent database record.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "without hardcoding table structure in Java"? You don't want to use any annotations?

Comment: Only optional. If I wish, I would declare a property and annotate it. But if not, I should be able to have dynamic properties. Any record, readen from database, should contain all fields, accessible by dynamic getters.

Comment: "dynamic properties", "dynamic getters"? You won't use standard POJO class for records?

Comment: Because I don't want to refactor them on each database structure change.

Comment: Suppose I have added new field or renamed old one. I don't want to refactor and recompile my application.

Answer (score 2):

Use SQLJ.  It satisfies all your requirements : "database first" continues to hold and database can change structure, and you won't have to rewrite any kind of ORM resource because there *is no* ORM resource.

That said, of course you are *never* going to be able to avoid having the change your code if a database change is such that it negatively impacts the *very validity* of a query you've got included in your sources.  I hope you weren't expecting that kind of silver bullet.

And as for "Simultaneously I wish to have ... object instance represent database record" *OF COURSE THAT IS IMPOSSIBLE* (if the class structure is supposed to be at all times a perfect image of the table/query structure) and if your system is "more resilient" to "not being a perfect image" then you *WILL* have the phenomenon that for some data in the database it is impossible to make it to your classes (because class has not been adapted to include an additional column) or that for some fields in your classes it will become impossible to get populated (because their source has been removed from the db).  I'm pretty sure once you've *experienced* such phenomena, you'll reconsider having said you want that kind of resilience.  The alternative is just more runtime errors any time a db has changed structure.  Really sure that THAT's what you want ?

Really.  What you're asking sounds a lot like "I want working programs but I don't want to have to code".

Answer (score 1):

Since you were looking for answers in the context of different ORMs, I'll respond from the jOOQ perspective. While jOOQ works best with generated code for your tables / columns, this is an option only. An example for using jOOQ with "plain SQL" tables and columns can be seen in the manual here:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-standalone-sql-builder

```
create.select(field("BOOK.TITLE"), field("AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME"), field("AUTHOR.LAST_NAME"))
      .from(table("BOOK"))
      .join(table("AUTHOR"))
      .on(field("BOOK.AUTHOR_ID").equal(field("AUTHOR.ID")))
      .where(field("BOOK.PUBLISHED_IN").equal(1948))
      .fetch();
```

Resulting records can then be manipulated by using column names in `String` form:

```
Object value = record.getValue("TITLE");
```

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating entities manually, there is a way for generating entity from database tables in eclipse through JPA Tools.

After which, you can use those entities class for spring data too.

Please refer the [link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jpt.doc.user%2Ftasks021.htm) eclipse help document.